# Carregar dados sem refersh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tenho um formulário passando os dados por GET para uma API, o method coloquei vazio pra carregar na mesma página, quando voltam os dados eu coloco dentro de uma div para exibi-los, mas preciso que faça isso sem dar refresh na página, preciso que só carregue a did com os dados, não tenho as manha de Jquery.

Fiz isso

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function () {

            var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "index.php",
                data: dados,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    alert('deu certo');
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

Mas preciso que os dados retornem para uma tabela e não para um alert.

Comment: Acredito que o problema é que você ainda não manja muito de javascript, talvez estudar um pouco mais a linguagem pura seja uma boa idéia antes de tentar frameworks e bibliotecas. Uma observação, o atributo `success` está obsoleto nas últimas versões foi trocado pela função `done`, de uma olhada na documentação

Answer (score 0):

Faça uma função que receba um parametro(data-json, xml, etc) e a chame dentro do evento sucess do ajax passado a data como argumento, para renderizar a tabela tem diversos modos, acessando diretamente a tabela com o DOM e mudando seus valores, usando templates, dentre outras.

```
function renderTable(data) {//exemplo console.log(data); // aqui os codigo para renderizar a tabela}
```